# Bruce J Mitchell (aka MST3K's "Zap Rowsdower") RIP

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Bruce J. Mitchell, known to MST3K fans everywhere as the hockey-haired drifter Zap Rowsdower from the sci-fi cult film *The Final Sacrifice* passed away on [April 28th, 2018](http://www.mhfh.com/mitchell-bruce-jawn-michael/).

[image: Zap Rowsdower]

Here's an [interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eGAxPEeNtVM&t=49s) with Mitchell from a few years ago. Seems like he was a pretty neat guy.

Comment: What MST episode was this movie played in?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd, it's episode 10 of Season 9 (0910).  Valorum has the ep linked in his answer.  Definitely worth a look if you're at all a MISTIE.  IMHO, it's one of the top 5 MST3K eps of all time.

Comment: Thanks. I can't see Valroum's link, so I'll have to look this up later.

Answer (score 5):

Will he be spoken of in the same hushed tones as Olivier, Hopkins and Day-Lewis? Only time will tell.

That being said, I've liked him in everything I've ever seen him in :-)